# Why it takes longer to full scan a table in MongoDB?

Tags: mongodb

I have made a test with 10 M rows of data. Each row has 3 integer and 2 string columns. First I import this data to mongoDB which is a single shard. I do a simple "where" query with db.table.find() on a non-index columns. The query fetches a single row which takes roughly in 7 seconds.

On the same hardware I load the same data to a c# list which is in memory. I do a while loop to scan all 10M data and do a simple equal control to emulate where query. It takes only around 650 ms which is much more faster than MongoDB.

I have a 32 GB machine so mongodb is having no problem to memory map the table.

Why mongoDB is much slower? Is it because the mongoDB is keeping the data in a data structure which is hard to full scan or is it because memory mapping in not the same as keeping a data in a variable.

Comment: Have you tried your test just once? Did you take into account warmup costs? I'd run each test 100 times, discard  5 highest and 5 lowest results and average the rest.

Comment: I repeated the test on mongoDB 10 times and the best time is 7423 miliseconds and worst is 8333 ms.

Comment: I'm rather late to the party here, but there's another possble difference between your C# code and your mongo query.  I suppose that your while loop stops looping when you've found your one record, but that your where query doesn't limit the result set to 1 result.  If that's true, then your C# code isn't necessarily scanning all of the 10M records, but the mongo query is (because it can't determine that there is only one result without looking at all of the records).  But I'm just guessing, so this is a good example of the value of posting sample code when asking questions.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As Remon pointed out you are definitely comparing apples to oranges in this test.

To understand a bit more on what is happening behind the scenes in that table scan, read through the MongoDB internals [here](http://horicky.blogspot.com/2012/04/mongodb-architecture.html). (Look under the Storage model)

[image]
There is the concept of extents which represents a contiguous disk space.

Each extent points to a linked list of docs.

The doc contains the data in BSON format. So now you can imagine how we would retrieve data.

Now the beauty of having an index is aptly shown at the right top corner. MongoDB uses a BTree structure to navigate which is pretty fast.

Try changing your test to have some warm up runs and use an index.

**UPDATE** : I have done some testing as a part of my day job to compare the performance of JBoss Cache (an in memory Java Cache) with MongoDB as an application cache (queries against _id). The results are quite comparable.

Answer (score 1):

Where to start..

First of all the test is completely apples and oranges. Loading a dataset into memory and doing a completely in-memory scan of it is in no way equal to a table scan on any database.

I'm also willing to bet you're doing your test on cold data and MongoDB performance improves dramatically as it swaps hot data into memory. Please note that MongoDB doesn't preemptively swap data into memory. It does so if, and only if, the data is accessed frequently (or at all, depending). Actually it's more accurate to say the OS does since MongoDB's storage engine is built on top of MMFs (memory mapped files).

So in short, your test isn't a good test and the way you're testing MongoDB isn't producing accurate results. You're testing a theoretical best case with your C# equivalent that on top of that is considerably less complex than the database code.

Comment: What makes the data 'hot' for mongoDB. I repeat the test which is only a db.testTable.find({'eventName':3}) just after I get the result so I assume that my data is hot. I also think that something is different and trying to figure ot what it is.

Comment: The difference is that one is a 10 line piece of code and the other is a database.